# SSH while read line loop without using remote commands

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a list of IP addresses I need to ssh into, making unique changes to each one. I tried doing

`while read -r line; do
ssh -n $line; done < file`

but I need to manually run commands and checks on each device. The second I login it kicks me out to the next one. Are there any read line or ssh options that can allow me to do this?

Comment: That outputs the contents of the file into the terminal of the remote device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tell `read` to use a different FD, then you can remove the `-n` from ssh.

```
while read -u 3 ...
do
   ...
done 3< file
```

Comment: Ooh, nice, didn't know about `-u`, points for you ;)